# how to get data from php to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have .php file and I have js file. I am trying to make bar chart. Now I have selected some data to my database. and now I don't know how can I get data from .php file to .js file.

I have this code:

//.js file

```
var data, options;

// replace this data with my selected data
data = {
    labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
    series: [
        [19, 29, 28, 44, 39, 48, 54],
    ]
};

options = {
    height: 300,
    showArea: true,
    showLine: true,
    showPoint: true,
    fullWidth: true,
    axisX: {
        showGrid: false
    },
    lineSmooth: false,
};

new Chartist.Line('#headline-chart', data, options);
```

/**PHP FILE**/

```
    $chart6 = $controller->runQuery("SELECT DATE(pay_date) `DATE`, SUM(amount) daily_amount, DATE_FORMAT(pay_date,'%a') DAYNAME FROM tbl_paid WHERE DATE(pay_date) BETWEEN DATE(:today) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND DATE(:today) GROUP BY DATE(pay_date);"); 
    $chart6->execute(array(":today"=>$today));
    while($fetch = $chart6->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
   {
          $data ="{labels:".$fetch['DATE']."-".$fetch['DAYNAME']." series:".$fetch['daily_amount']."}";
   }
```

Comment: send ajax request to get the data and use the return data as value for the chart. Return a JSON so that chart will be able to use it as value

Comment: Never manually create json, it is error prone and takes more effort than to use json serializer in whatever language you are working with. In php use `json_encode($array)`

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Can use ajax and initialize chart once you receive the data or you can print json into javascript variable in a `<script>` tag and pass that variable to chart config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about ajax in javascript and make an ajax request that gets the json object from PHP then process that in your javascript:

Example (with some improvement to your PHP code)

PHP

```
$chart6 = $controller->runQuery("SELECT DATE(pay_date) `DATE`, SUM(amount) daily_amount, DATE_FORMAT(pay_date,'%a') DAYNAME FROM tbl_paid WHERE DATE(pay_date) BETWEEN DATE(:today) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND DATE(:today) GROUP BY DATE(pay_date);"); 
$chart6->execute(array(":today"=>$today));
$labels = array();
$series = array()
while($fetch = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $labels[] = $fetch['DAYNAME'];
  $series0[] = $fetch['daily_amount'];
}
$series[] = $series0;

// add the labels and series to an array, then convert that to json
$data = array('labels' => $labels, 'series' => $series);
echo json_encode($data);
```

JS:

```
// Make an Ajax request, here I am using jQuery $.getJSON  but you can use $.get or $.post if you need to have it as a post request, or even $.ajax

$.getJSON('https://example.com/database_fetch_page.php', function(data) {
  new Chartist.Line('#headline-chart', data, options);
});
```

Comment: Thank you and it works. but error on my graph. because the series requires output like this series: [
            [19, 29, 28, 44, 39, 48, 54],
        ]